# SQL - Select using attributes from two tables

Tags: sql

I am having an issue in extracting data using data of two tables in SQL.

```
select A, B, C, D
from Table_one T1
where A in (select T2.A from Table_two T2
where T2.E <> 'ZZZ');
```

This returns A, B, C, D where E in T2 is not ZZZ.
However, when I add another where clause like below,
it returns data where T2 is ZZZ also.

```
select A, B, C, D
from Table_one T1
where A in (select T2.A from Table_two T2
where T2.E <> 'ZZZ')
and D <> 0 ;
```

This ignores "T2.E <> 'ZZZ'" part, but "D<>0" is not ignored.
Why is this happening?

Comment: post sample data and the database your using

Comment: Your queries seems fine - this shouldn't happen. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] using the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Comment: I agree with Zohar. @Sen Could you provide data samples: 1. source tables 2. result of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have duplicates in `Table_two`. For some of those duplicates, one has the value of `ZZZ` and the other does not.

You are using the wrong logic if you want to exclude rows that have a `ZZZ` in `table_two`.  I would recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select A, B, C, D
from Table_one T1
where not exists (select 1
                  from Table_two T2
                  where T1.A = T2.A and
                        T2.E = 'ZZZ'
                 ) and
      D <> 0 ;
```